# How to share weights to "reuse" an existing network

Tags: tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, tf.keras

**Introduction**

I am working with the Value network shown in the [figure below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQrYm.png)  The variable X refers to the current state and Y is the state at the following time step, i.e. the future state.

**Explanation**

It is the "state value function" that should be "used twice" since it is the same function, V, that is evaluated with two different arguments X and Y. The network itself is a convolutional NN which I already have implemented. I believe I have all the necessary layers are correctly implemented for the reward network, r(X).

The value network, V(X), uses the same convolutional layers so I believe that in principle it is correct, except for the sharing of weights from V(X) to V(Y). At the moment I have two different value networks, one for the X and another for the Y states, which I know to be wrong since the networks should represent exactly the same function.

**Question**

Can anyone tell me what's the right / optimal way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PyTorch or Keras or TensorFlow, you can just stack the inputs as a batch and pass them through a single network.

Example in PyTorch:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
x = torch.rand(1,3,64,64) # input x
y = torch.rand(1,3,64,64) # input y
cnn = nn.Conv2d(3,10,kernel_size=5) # network
input = torch.cat((x,y),dim=0) # stack them batch-wise
output = cnn(input) # pass both x and y through the network as a single pass
x_out = output[0] # get the output of x
y_out = output[1] # get the output of y
```

You could do something similar in TensorFlow as well as Keras.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. What you suggest is indeed one version I have tried. My groupmates and I seem to agree that the issues we see in the results might stem from doing just that. To stack the inputs means that I need to define the input layer to have an input that is twice the length of the array that represents state X. Does this no mean that this network is in essence different from the corresponding network that takes in only one state at a time?

Comment: No, you do not need to change the definition of the input layer size as you are only changing the batch size of the input. The inputs accepted by the networks are either [None, h,w,c] or [None, c,h,w] depending on the framework used. Where the 'None' represents the batch size and you can set it to any value you want. As you can see in the network defined in my answer, I have not changed the input layer dimension to accommodate both x and y.